# Is it possible to perform a pre-test post study with different sample groups?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, statistical-power

I want to perform a study in which I compare two groups before and after an intervention (communication training) on patient experience.
This will take place at an outpatient clinic in which patients do not often come back, meaning that in my study period the pre-test sample will differ from the post-test sample. It is a selective patient population in a specialized clinic for this rare disease, where patient often come only to get diagnosed. Due to the rarity I also will not be able to include a control group.
I understand I cannot perform a repeated measurements anova, but would it be suitable to perform a anova? Or is there a better way which could take in account the limitation of between subject variation?

Comment: How would you address the scientific sceptic who wonders whether the people who appear for a post-test sample might have had a very different response to the intervention than those who don't appear? As an extreme example of the concern, suppose the intervention kills most of the patients, so the only ones you evaluate post-intervention are the survivors.  How would you learn about the deaths using an ANOVA of the survivors only?

Comment: Of course this a valid point. I will add some details in the question. The intervention is a communication training for the clinicians and one of the variables I want to investigate is regarding patient experience.

Comment: It can be useful to know how many measures you can take by person (1 or 2? can you expect 10 in some cases?) and how big is " a few " (10? 25? 100?).